# Install Python package with read-permission on Arch-Linux

Tags: python, arch-linux

I have tried Arch Linux recently and as I'm a Python programmer wanted to install the `request` package. To do so I needed to install the `pip` Python package manager by calling

```
$ sudo easy_install pip
```

Next I installed the requests package with

```
$ sudo pip3 install requests
```

If I now start Python and import the requests package the package content is completely missing. Normally there should be a bunch of classes and functions.

```
Python 3.5.1 (default, Mar  3 2016, 09:29:07)
[GCC 5.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> dir(requests)
['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

So I had a look at the `/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages` directory where the installed Python packages are located and discovered that the `requests` directory doesn't have read permission for everyone.

```
$ ls /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages
drwxr-x---  4 root root   4096 Mar  1 17:04 requests
drwxr-x---  2 root root   4096 Mar  1 17:04 requests-2.13.0.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root   4096 Apr 14  2016 setuptools
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Apr 11  2016 setuptools-20.7.0-py3.5.egg-info
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Oct 11  2015 six-1.10.
```

Is there a way to install new Python packages in Arch with the right privileges? I've used Debian before and went through the same procedure for Python package installation and never discovered this issue.

Comment: You can install it with pacman:
`sudo pacman -S python-requests`
or with pip3:
`pip3 install requests`
Running pip with root is not recommended. 
If you run `sudo python3` now, you should be able to import installed packages with `sudo pip3 install`,

Comment: Yes, `sudo pacman -S python-requests` works but is for Python2 only. I also tried `pip3 install` without sudo but there I get a permission error.

Comment: python2-requests should be the package for python2.
It seems that python2 is a [dependency](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/python-requests/) on arch, but not on debian.
If that is an option, remove pip3, and reinstall it again with:
`sudo pacman -S python-pip` and then run `pip3 install requests`

Comment: I just tried install python-pip with `sudo pacman -S python-pip`. I did it on a virtual machine and wiped it before I did so. However `pip3 install requests` results now in a `Distribution not found` Error:

    `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==9.0.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application`.

The same when I use `sudo pip3 install requests`. Strange thing.

Comment: I had to update my packages with `pacman -Syyu`. Also I needed to set manually *write permission* for my user to `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages` for being able to pip install. No it works. But now every user can use pip install :( On Debian installing can only be done with sudo but every user can use the packages. So I'm asking myself what is differnt here.